# Error on TesseractOCR in Xcode8

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to build TesseractOCR sample project, [Passport Scanner on GitHub](https://github.com/evermeer/PassportScanner), with xcode8.

After converted to swift3, xcode seems not to recognize headers of TesseractOCR library.

Xcode8 shows many errors with like this image.

[image]

What is the reson of these error?
(But on XCode7, it works well.)

Is there any changes on using C library on swift in xcode8?